# Close the window when closing the last tab

Tags: browser, opera, browser-tabs

In Opera, the window doesn't close when closing the last tab.

I've looked in the settings but can't find any way to change this. **Is it even possible to do this? If so, where?**

Comment: What version of Opera are you running? What OS? My Opera closes with the last tab being closed.

Comment: @thesoundman20 I am using version 39.0.2256.71 on W10

Comment: what happens when you close the last tab? does it go to speed dial?

Comment: @thesoundman20 yes it does

Comment: Ok I apologize, i tested it with another opera window open. apparently if you only have one window open when you close the last tab they are not allowing it to close the window. In [this](http://forums.opera.com/discussion/1872644/opera-37-0-2178-32-speed-dial-search-closing-last-tab-now-closes-browser/p1) post the opera employee says the following:If there is only one Opera window - we are not allowing to close the last tab there, in fact there shouldn't even be a button to close the last tab on the last window.

Comment: @thesoundman20 Oh wow this really sucks. Ofcourse there is always the X button to close the window but it's just slightly faster to close the tab in some cases. Oh well. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ctrl+W closes the tabs while Ctrl+Shift+W closes the browser. So maybe instead of clicking the X button you can press Ctrl+W to close the tabs then when you get to the last on Add Shift. Its not exactly what you are trying to accomplish but at least its a relatively easy alternative.